# Ajax not working, JavaScript and PHP works

Tags: jquery

My following code is inserting data into the MySQL database; but the AJAX code is not working at all. I have tested it with IE and Firefox browsers. The AJAX is suppose to display a div "erreur" if the "pseudonyme" is found on the database, or the div "bonPseudo" if the "pseudonyme" is not found in the database.
Any hint please? Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head><title>jQuery + AJAX + PHP/MySQL</title>
        <span id="result"></span>

        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="script/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>  
        <script src="script/mon_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
             $(function() {
                  $('#txtPseudonyme').keyup(function() {
                      var pseudonyme=$('#txtPseudonyme').val();
                      $.ajax({ 
                              type:"POST",
                              url:"recherche.php",
                              data:'txtPseudonyme='+pseudonyme,
                              success:function(data) {
                                 if(data==1) {
                                    $("#erreur").fadeIn().text('Ce pseudonyme existe déjà!');
                                    $("#bonPseudo").fadeOut();
                                } else {
                                    $("#bonPseudo").fadeIn().text('Vous pouvez choisir ce pseudonyme.');
                                    $('#erreur').fadeOut();
                                }
                              }
                       });
                  });
              });
             </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contenu"><!--pour centrer le formulaire-->
            <form id="monFormulaire" action="recherche.php" method="POST">
                <label for="txtPseudonyme"> Pseudonyme: </label>
                <input type="text" name="txtPseudonyme" id="txtPseudonyme">
                <span id="erreur"></span><!--Pour afficher un message d'erreur si pseudonyme existe déjà-->
                <span id="bonPseudo"></span><!--Pour afficher un message d'erreur si pseudonyme n'existe pas-->
                <label for="txtNom"> Nom: </label>
                <input type="text" name="txtNom" id="txtNom">
                <label for="txtPrenoms"> Prénom(s): </label>
                <input type="text" name="txtPrenoms" id="txtPrenoms">
                <label for="txtAge"> Age: </label>
                <input type="text" id="txtAge" name="txtAge">
                <label for="txtCourriel"> Courriel: </label>
                <input type="text" id="txtCourriel" name="txtCourriel">
                <input type="submit">
                <input type="reset">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What $_POST[] value is expected in your PHP script? You may be passing the `data:` incorrectly.

Comment: PHP script gets the $_POST[] value correctly.

Comment: Could be wrong but I think `$function() { ... }` should be `$(function () { ... });` It looks like you're attempting to do the shorthand syntax for `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`. Correct me if I'm wrong on that.

Comment: Hi War10ck, I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing {} in if else, try it...

Edit:

Your jquery function & ajax is also not in correct format, 
declare function as

> $(function() {//function code goes here});

We are declaring function in jquery, so the

> $();

should contain

> function(){//Code}

Again same format for .keyup() function 
Change

> .keyup(function()) { ...} To .keyup(function() { ...});

Same in case of Ajax. You are closing ajax in wrong format. It should be

> $.ajax({});

& when passing value as parameter use

> 'variable='+value

there are also other mistakes like,

> $('txtPseudonyme') use # to refer the field(id=#,class=.,etc)

Here is the full function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#txtPseudonyme').keyup(function() {
            var pseudonyme=$('#txtPseudonyme').val();
            $.ajax({ 
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"recherche.php",
                    data:'txtPseudonyme='+pseudonyme,
                    success:function(data) {
                       if(data==1) {
                          $("#erreur").fadeIn().text('Value 1');
                          $("#bonPseudo").fadeOut();
                      } else {
                          $("#bonPseudo").fadeIn().text('Value 2');
                          $('#erreur').fadeOut();
                      }
                    }
             });
        });
     });
    </script>
```

Work out with Basics of jquery & ajax, try tutorials ...

Comment: iMmo you are right about the {}. I've updated the code above, but it still doesn't.

Comment: Thanks IMmo. Now Ajax is reacting; but there is still a problem that comes I think from my code: whatever the value I type in the input text txtPseudonyme, I've the text of value 2 displayed. That is not correct. Value 2 should be displayed only if the value of txtPseudonyme is not in the database, and value 1 should be displayed if the value of txtPseudonyme is in the database.

Comment: Probably your data is always empty
use an alert
`alert("Return Data"+data);` if its empty, problem is in your query

Comment: The "data" object is not empty. I think the problem comes from the "keyup" function: whatever I type in the input box, if even it is only one character, or if even it is a blank character, text "value 1" is displayed. I would like that after I type a name in the input box, and after I release the last key, that "value 1" or "value 2" displays depending of the case.

Comment: @cProg the code which i gave u works for me in the same scenario,When we enter value as 1 in txtbox, it gives me Value 1 div & in all other cases it gives me Value 2 div.